# How can I join proper path with move_uploaded_file function?

Tags: file, path, upload

I have a problem with `move_uploaded_file` function. I don't know why it doesn't work, maybe it is something wrong with path in `init.php`. I have few files in which are correlated, so I decided to show you my repository:
https://github.com/pchudzin/Learning-PHP-OOP/tree/master/PhotoGallerySystem
Here you can download my code, there is also database file.

I have 2 warnings and error message from my code ("the file directory probably does not have permission"):

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(SITE_ROOT\admin\images\13-uklad-1.png):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs_OOP_PHP\Learning-PHP-OOP\PhotoGallerySystem\admin\includes\photo.php
>   on line 62
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php1C1.tmp' to 'SITE_ROOT\admin\images\13-uklad-1.png'
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs_OOP_PHP\Learning-PHP-OOP\PhotoGallerySystem\admin\includes\photo.php
>   on line 62

Absolute path to images folder:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs_OOP_PHP\Learning-PHP-OOP\PhotoGallerySystem\admin\images

The images folder has read/write permissions.

I will be grateful for your help!
init.php

```
<?php

defined('DS') ? null : define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

defined('DS') ? null : define( 'SITE_ROOT', 'C:' . DS . 'xampp' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'kurs_OOP_PHP' . DS . 'Learning-PHP-OOP' . DS . 'PhotoGallerySystem' );

defined('INCLUDES_PATH') ? null : define('INCLUDES_PATH', 'SITE_ROOT' . DS . 'admin'. DS . 'includes');

require_once("functions.php");
require_once("new_config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("db_object.php");
require_once("user.php");
require_once("photo.php");
require_once("session.php");

?>
```

photo.php

```
<?php

  class Photo extends Db_object {

    protected static $db_table = "photos";
    protected static $db_table_fields = array('photo_id', 'title', 'description', 'filename', 'type', 'size');
    public $photo_id;
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $filename;
    public $type;
    public $size;

    public $tmp_path;
    public $upload_directory = "images";
    public $errors = array();

    public $upload_errors_array = array(
      UPLOAD_ERR_OK => "There is no error, the file uploaded with success.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => "No file was uploaded.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "Missing a temporary folder.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Failed to write file to disk.",
      UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => "A PHP extension stopped the file upload."
    );
    // This is passing $_FILES['uploaded_file'] as an argument
    public function set_file( $file ) {

      if( empty( $file ) || !$file || !is_array( $file ) ) {
        $this->errors[] = "There was no file uploaded here";
        return false;
      } else if( $file['error'] != 0 ) {
        $this->errors[] = $this->upload_errors_array[ $file['error'] ];
        return false;
      } else {
        $this->filename = basename( $file['name'] );
        $this->tmp_path = $file['tmp_name'];
        $this->type = $file['type'];
        $this->size = $file['size'];
      }
    }

    public function save() {
      if( $this->photo_id ) {
        $this->update();
      } else {
        if( !empty( $this->errors ) ) {
          return false;
        }
        if( empty( $this->filename ) || empty( $this->tmp_path ) ) {
          $this->erros[] = "the file was not available";
          return false;
        }
        $target_path = 'SITE_ROOT' . DS . 'admin'. DS . $this->upload_directory . DS . $this->filename;

        if ( file_exists( $target_path ) ) {
          $this->errors = "The file {$this->filename} already exists";
          return false;
        }
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $this->tmp_path, $target_path ) ) {
          if( $this->create() ) {
            unset( $this->tmp_path);
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          $this->errors[] = "the file directory probably does not have permission";
          return false;
        }

      }

    }

  }

?>
```

upload.php

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php

  if( !$session->is_signed_in() ) {
    redirect( "login.php" );
  }

?>

<?php

  $message="";

  if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $photo = new Photo();
    $photo->title = $_POST['title'];
    $photo->set_file( $_FILES['file_upload'] );

    if( $photo->save() ) {
      $message = "Photo uploaded succesfully";
    } else {
      $message = join("<br>", $photo->errors);
    }
  }
 ?>


        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

            <?php include("includes/top_nav.php"); ?>

            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <?php include("includes/side_nav.php"); ?>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>



        <div id="page-wrapper">
          <div class="container-fluid">

              <!-- Page Heading -->
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <h1 class="page-header">
                          Upload
                          <small>Subheading</small>
                      </h1>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php echo $message ?>
                        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="file" name="file_upload">
                          </div>
                          <input type="submit" name="submit">
                        </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->

          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

  <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

db_object.php

```
<?php

  class Db_object {

    protected static $db_table = "users";

    public static function find_all() {

      return static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table . " ");
    }
    public static function find_by_id( $user_id ) {

      global $database;
      $the_result_array=static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table . " WHERE id=$user_id LIMIT 1");

      return !empty( $the_result_array ) ? array_shift( $the_result_array ) : false;
    }
    public static function find_by_query( $sql ) {

      global $database;
      $result_set = $database->query( $sql );
      $the_object_array = array();

      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result_set ) ) {

        $the_object_array[] = static::instantation($row);
      }
      return $the_object_array;
    }
    public static function instantation( $the_record ) {

      $calling_class = get_called_class();

      $the_object = new $calling_class;

      foreach ($the_record as $the_attribute => $value) {

        if( $the_object->has_the_attribute( $the_attribute ) ) {

          $the_object->$the_attribute = $value;
        }
      }
      return $the_object;
    }
    private function has_the_attribute( $the_attribute ) {

      $object_properties = get_object_vars($this);
      return array_key_exists( $the_attribute, $object_properties );
    }
    protected function properties() {

      $properties = array();
      foreach (static::$db_table_fields as $db_field) {
        if( property_exists($this, $db_field) ) {
          $properties[$db_field] = $this->$db_field;
        }
      }
      return $properties;
    }
    protected function clean_properties() {
      global $database;

      $clean_properties = array();

      foreach ($this->properties() as $key => $value) {
        $clean_properties[$key] = $database->escape_string($value);
      }
      return $clean_properties;
    }

    public function save() {
      return isset( $this->id ) ? $this->update() : $this->create();
    }
    public function create() {
      global $database;

      $properties = $this->clean_properties();

      $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$db_table . "(" . implode(",", array_keys($properties)) . ")";
      $sql .= "VALUES ('" . implode("','", array_values($properties)) . "')";

      if( $database->query( $sql ) ) {
        $this->id = $database->the_insert_id();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    public function update() {
      global $database;

      $properties = $this->properties();
      $properties_pairs = array();

      foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
        $properties_pairs[] ="{$key}='{$value}'";
      }
      $sql = "UPDATE " . static::$db_table . " SET ";
      $sql .= implode(", ", $properties_pairs);
      $sql .= " WHERE id= " . $database->escape_string( $this->id );

      $database->query( $sql );

      return ( mysqli_affected_rows( $database->connection ) == 1 ) ? true : false;
    }
    public function delete() {
      global $database;
      $sql = "DELETE FROM " . static::$db_table . " ";
      $sql .= "WHERE id=" . $database->escape_string( $this->id );
      $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

      $database->query( $sql );

      return ( mysqli_affected_rows( $database->connection ) == 1 ) ? true : false;
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line:

```
$target_path = 'SITE_ROOT' . DS . 'admin'. DS . $this->upload_directory . DS . $this->filename;
```

is using the literal string 'SITE_ROOT' when you mean to use the constant `SITE_ROOT`. So I think your line should read:

```
$target_path = SITE_ROOT . DS . 'admin'. DS . $this->upload_directory . DS . $this->filename;
```

Comment: It was exactly like you said. Firstly I made SITE_ROOT without quotation marks, but then I got this message:  SITE_ROOT - assumed 'SITE_ROOT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs_OOP_PHP\Learning-PHP-OOP\PhotoGallerySystem\admin\includes\init.php on line 7

Warning: Use of undefined constant SITE_ROOT - assumed 'SITE_ROOT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\kurs_OOP_PHP\Learning-PHP-OOP\PhotoGallerySystem\admin\includes\photo.php on line 56

Comment: @chudyy If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted solution to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry kmoser, but your answer didn't help me. I still have 2 warnings.

Comment: It looks like you need to change this line:
``defined('DS') ? null : define( 'SITE_ROOT', 'C:' . DS . 'xampp' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'kurs_OOP_PHP' . DS . 'Learning-PHP-OOP' . DS . 'PhotoGallerySystem' );``
to this: ``define( 'SITE_ROOT', 'C:' . DS . 'xampp' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'kurs_OOP_PHP' . DS . 'Learning-PHP-OOP' . DS . 'PhotoGallerySystem' );``